# Shut Down Web Application

Tags: asp.net, iis, sql-server-agent

I need to shut down my web application during maintenance process, have already gone through many ways like putting app_offline.htm in root directory , disabling the Runtime or disabling it manually via server but i what i need to implement is to do this process completely automated.

What i have is the start and end dates for shut down and flag for those days i.e whether application needed to be shut down on those dates.

Solution that i already have is to create a job in sql server agent which creates and deletes the app_offline.htm file in and from the root directory but what the problem is i need to give static path for the root directory of my application which i don not want to do.

Comment: what version of IIS are you using? Instead of giving the static path, you can probe the IIS to get the exact path.

Comment: I am Using IIS 7.5, I have to probe iis from sql server which i don't know how it can be done, If possible please guide me.

Comment: you can stop the application pool programmatically. Not sure if that is your requirement. See my answer to get the physical path of the app.

Comment: Code you have provided me with will work in asp.net platform not on sql server..

Comment: @Ariana...true...but you already have a job in sql server. May be you can modify it to call the C# code as I described below

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **appcmd** command line utility for managing sites on IIS. It's located in `%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\APPCMD`. I think it is available in IIS v7 and above only though, not sure if your using an older version of IIS.

To stop and start a site, the command will look like the following:

```
%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\APPCMD stop site <Your Site's Name>

%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\APPCMD start site <Your Site's Name>
```

More info on the appcmd utility is here: http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/getting-started-with-iis/getting-started-with-appcmdexe

Answer (score 1):

This is part of the answer which deals with probing the IIS to get the physical path. It might need some tweaking

```
         //eg of site = 'Default Web Site'
        //eg of Application = 'MySite'
        var appName = "MySite";
        //Initializes a new instance of the ServerManager class by using the default path of the ApplicationHost.config file.
        ServerManager mgr = new ServerManager();
        var applications = mgr.Sites.Cast<Site>().SelectMany(s => s.Applications);

        var app = applications.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Path.Equals("/" + appName));

        IList<string> physicalPaths = app.VirtualDirectories.Cast<VirtualDirectory>().Select(v => v.PhysicalPath).ToList();

        //Calling dispose manually. Per MSDN, cannot wrap the ServerManager instance in 'Using' as it causes memory leaks
        mgr.Dispose();

        //Releasing the reference to the Server Manager, per MSDN guidance
        mgr = null;
        return physicalPaths;
```

Comment: `mgr` should be in a `using` block, and you don't need to set it to `null`.

Comment: @John per MSDN, wrapping the manager in the using block causes memory leakes

Comment: Please post the link that says memory leaks are caused. It makes no sense, since Dispose does the same thing.

Comment: I found this URL where the users have complained about memory leaks. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.servermanager(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Those are _comments_ that think they see a memory leak, and as far as I can tell, they're just talking about an increase in working set, not an actual memory leak. Calling `mgr.Dispose();` does _precisely_ what the `using` block does. There is no difference at all. `using` is just syntactic sugar for `ServerManager mgr = new ServerManager(); try { ... } finally {mgr.Dispose();}`

Comment: I will give +1 to you for now. But I am positive I did find somewhere on MSDN explicitly suggesting to not use 'using' for ServerManager. I don't recollect. But I will post, if I find it.

Comment: Dont scare us like that! we have production code doign using on ServerManager. I can not belive that is true, that mgr.dispose() should be any better then doing using. Also what John Saunders is saying.

Answer (score 0):

One issue that you have here is that web application work on a request basis. You make a request, request is processed and returned. Therefore, to rely on this principle to shutdown your application will not work. What you need is to register a scheduler of some type in `Application_Start` that would configure itself based on the values in the database. Although I am not sure which scheduling mechanism would be appropriate, you might want to look at `Timer` (but you must keep a reference to the this object because of garbage collection) or Task scheduler in [System.Threading.Tasks namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.aspx).

I might be wrong with a choice of classes but this could be a starting point.

Now, as for you design decision, I would avoid it completely. If your web application can create **app_offline.html** or rename a file into that one, you have no way of bringing the server back online without manual intervention by removing the file. Instead of that why not create some maintenance Windows Service that can query the database and take offline and bring back online again? If you don't care about bringing the web application online automatically then you should not care about taking it offline automatically.

Another thing to consider is a human mistake in configuring the time when application goes offline. Wrongly configured time can bring down your application much too sooner or much later. Wouldn't it be easier if you created some batch scripts or PowerShell scripts that could take down and bring back up the web application? With the PowerShell script you can query IIS for your application without specifying any physical location.